# Turntable motor speed slow

Tags: turntable

I have an old Sony PS 300 turntable, 110V, and the motor got damaged due to connecting it directly to 220V electricity. Since then, I've bought more than 5 new motors, replaced the damaged one, and bought a new transformer to convert from 220 to 110, but still I am unable to reach the required speed. I get 40rpm instead of 45 and 29-30 instead of 35. Can anyone suggest a solutio?

Comment: I don't know how "old" that model is, but the very "old" electronic equipment get their timing information from the AC voltage (120V @ 60Hz / 230V @ 50Hz). In other words, for "old" equipment voltage conversion is only a part of the story.

Comment: You didn't say where you are.  Is it possible that your country uses 50 Hz power and the motor's speed is based on 60 Hz?  That would make the speed 83.3% of what it should be.

Comment: thanks, this is i think the issue, I live in Dubai and the turntable is very old, actually its a vintage, so what is the best solution for this issue, I always thought its the motor and kept on buying new motors but all gave same results

Comment: The slower speed is supposed to be 33⅓ rpm, not 35.

Answer (score 2):

Most countries with 110V power use a frequency of 60Hz and the majority of countries with 220V use 50Hz. This would explain the speed difference.

Those Sony turntables would have been produced for markets worldwide, so there should be motors available for 220V/50Hz. The easiest solution would be to find one.

Here's a [related question](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/3518/turntable-spins-faster-after-moving-to-a-new-country-with-different-power-spec?rq=1) from someone who has the opposite problem.

Comment: An odd exception is the Philippines which (mostly) uses 220V but 60Hz.  An IBM engineer that I knew found it very irritating.

Comment: honestly, i don't want to buy a new turntable as I love this vintage one but I am very irritated that I cannot make it reach the right speed and bought few convertors but none of it work as expected

Comment: @AhmadTaher You don't need a new turntable, just the *correct* motor for your local power.

Comment: From what I've read, you may be able to use a UPS as a frequency converter.  If it can accept whatever your local power is and produces 110V 60Hz, that would solve the problem.  And as a bonus, you can keep your turntable running even when the power is out.